# Split the array by anything that isn't a letter

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, ruby-2.3, parrot-os

I have a class that will check a users environment to find out if they have `python` installed, the classes purpose is to check if the user has multiple versions of python installed and to not default to three:

```
class CheckForPythonicVariables

  class << self

    def find_python_env_var
      py_path = []  # Results of the python env variables
      env_vars = ENV.to_h
      items = env_vars["Path"].split(";")  # Split the environment variables into an array
      items.each { |var|
        if var.to_s.include?("Python")  # Do you have python?
          py_path.push(var)
        end
      }
      py_path.each { |python|
        if python.include?("Python27")  # Python 2.7.x?
          return true
        elsif python.include?("Python3")  # Python 3.x.x?
          return false
        else
          raise "You do not have python installed"
        end
      }
    end

  end

end
```

Now this works, but it only works on Windows and a select few Linux `OS`, apparently `Parrot` is not one of them. Is there a way I can `#split()` the environment variables by anything that is not a letter? For example:

Windows env var: `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`
Parrot OS env var: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Note how the variables are split by either a semi-colon(`;`) or a colon(`:`), is there a way I could use the `#split()` function in ruby and split by anything that is not alphanumerical characters, or number? Or is there a better way to make sure that the user has `python 2.7.x` in their environment variables?

Comment: Maybe you could simply use split twice ? Or, according to the OS : MS-DOS or Unix, you chose the right separator ?
As an alternative, maybe you can use a command line/shell from Ruby to query the python version ? 'python -V'

Comment: @Hugo Problem with the system call (`system('python --version')` I did think of that) is that if they have multiple versions of python, it will default to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression matches all non-alphanumeric characters: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/`.

If you want to match all non-alphanumeric characters *excluding* forward-slash and backslash, use `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\\]/`.

Examples:

```
str = 'C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath'
str.split /[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\\]/
# => ["C", "\\Python27\\", "C", "\\Python27\\Scripts", "C", "\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath"]

str = '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games'
str.split /[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\\]/
# => ["/usr/local/bin", "/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/local/games", "/usr/games"]
```

Comment: It needs to work on all operating systems, but this is basically what I was looking for.

Comment: Added a Parrot OS example

Comment: You the man! Thank you, I'm not going to  accept it yet because I want to see other peoples ideas. But this is seems like a good start for me

Comment: On my system, Python is installed in `/Users/Jörg W Mittag/_Python`. Not sure what that will do to your script.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What kind of OS do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can check user's current python version like the following: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script))

```
%x(python -c 'print __import__("sys").version_info < (2,8)') == "True\n"
```

But if a user install python 3 and python 2.7, and they use python 3 now. The script cannot handle this situation.

Comment: That's the point of finding the variables, if they have 3 then it won't run, but if they have 2 and 3, it will create a temp variable called `python27` and run it from there.

Comment: This also doesn't work:   File "<string>", line 1
    'print
         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
false