# Error in python 2.7

Tags: python

```
print "Hello %s !!!" %("Pruthvish")
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I run this in python IDLE it prints the output, but when I run this program through windows powershell it gives me syntax error. Why does this happen?

Comment: What python version is IDLE and powershell using? To me it seems a diffirence between python2 and python3 at first glance

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)

Comment: for IDLE it's 2.7.11 and for powershell it's 5.1.14393.1359

Comment: There is no Python 5.1 so far. I guess that is the Powershell version.

Comment: Maybe running `python --version` in Powershell will give the Python version?

Comment: To make the code run, just add parentheses: ```( "Hello %s !!!" %("Pruthvish")```

Comment: Lukasz Rogalski thanks you are right I have both python 3 and python 2.7 that's why duplication occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Put Brackets for print statement

```
print ("Hello %s !!!" %("Pruthvish"));
```