# pygame installation via pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame in my python 2.7. I do it in this python because for some reason if I try to install pip in python 3.7 it won't work. From the terminal I entered:

```
sudo pip install pygame
```

And supposedly I installed it well, but when I try to do the import it tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

if i try to do again sudo `pip install pygame` :

```
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /home/cesar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.9.4)
```

Also, if I try to run `pip list` and look for pygame, it appears that the module is already installed:

```
pygame                        1.9.4
```

What may be happening? Why does python say that the requirement is already met if it is not able to import the module?

Comment: Perhaps you've installed pygame for Python 2.7 and are trying to import it with Python 3.7. Check the Python version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script

Comment: python runs python 2.7 and python3 runs python 3.7 :(

Comment: try ignoring the cache directory `pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pygame`

Comment: It says Requirement already up-to-date: pygame in /home/cesar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u using python 2.7.x or 3.x when runing script ?

Possibly, You run command like

```
python3 example.py
```

Or you run `python example.py` but `python --version` is outputting 3.x version if you are using Windows.

Can you try install pygame with pip3 ?

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Comment: If I try to install with pip3 says:

Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /home/cesar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.4)

I tryed run the script with python3 (which it runs python3.7) and python (which it runs python 2.7)

Comment: Hıms, I tried in my system and worked perfectly.

Can you try,

pip3 uninstall pygame, 
pip3 install pygame,
python3 example.py,

Comment: It says "Skipping pygame as it is not installed." In the second try of 

pip3 uninstall pygame

but when I try:

pip3 install pygame

then says:

 Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /home/cesar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.4)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. My suggestion would be,

Go on this website : https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Delete the current vesion of PyGame (.9.4) and follow the instructions on this video that I found for you on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGb5EX3XjdI

This will give you a tutorial of how to install PyGame 1.9.3 a lower version.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but I'm on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Try `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user`

See [Pygame GettingStarted](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: I tryed this one too

Comment: try `pip3 uninstall pygame` and then `pip3 install pygame`

Comment: It says "Skipping pygame as it is not installed." In the second try of pip3 uninstall pygame but when I try: pip3 install pygame then says: Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /home/cesar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.4)

Comment: Try upgrade setuptools `pip (or pip3) install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: Try with `sudo` too