# How to put variable in strings in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to follow along with a book and it says to put in the following code but it's not working.

The book is: Matthes, Eric. Python Crash Course, 2nd Edition (p. 21). No Starch Press. Kindle Edition.

```
first_name = "ada"
last_name = "lovelace"
full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
print(full_name)
```

Error:

```
 line 3
    full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It is in Python 3.7.3 according to terminal so that's not the issue

Comment: This syntax (f-strings) exists only since Python 3.6. You must be running an older version.

Comment: Your code looks fine and runs on my machine using Python 3.6.3.  You should double check which version of Python is running.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script) for how to do so.

Comment: Try `import sys; print(sys.version)` to check which version you are really running.

Comment: Don't believe the terminal check `sys.version` to be sure.

Comment: Your code runs fine under Python 3.6+. Please add the suggested code as first line of your script and run it again  - and comment out the line with the error...

Answer (score 1):

In 3.7.3, you could alternatively use .format() like this:

```
first_name = "ada"
last_name = "lovelace"
full_name = "{} {}".format(first_name, last_name)
print(full_name)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Well, no, you don't need to use `format`. The code given by the OP in the question if perfectly valid and runs fine on any version of Python >= 3.6.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I altered my answer to say "alternatively", because it is another way to get the answer that OP needed

Answer (score 1):

There are several other ways to achieve the same result, but the code you gave is valid on python 3.6 and above. It's likely that you are running an older version, even if the terminal doesn't say so. You can reliably check this with

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

There are other ways to get the same result, I'll list a few below.

```
first_name = "john"
last_name  = "doe"

full_name_m1 = first_name + " " + last_name
full_name_m2 = first_name + " %s" % last_name
full_name_m3 = "%s %d" % (first_name, last_name)

full_name_m4 = " "
for i in first_name:
    full_name_m4 += first_name[i]
full_name_m4 += " "
for i in last_name:
    full_name_m4 += last_name[I]
```

Sorry for formatting or typos, I'm on a mobile mobile. The last examples are definitely overkill, but seeing as you're learning python they might be interesting.