# Server stops at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ in python django

Tags: python, django, server

Here I am creating my first Django application that is basically a polls app. I have followed these steps:

- Created a django app in pycharm.
- Wrote two tables in models.py.
- Done  "python manage.py makemigrations".
- It successfully created my migrations.
- Done "python manage.py createsuperuser", set its username and
  password.
- Now doing, "python manage.py runserver", Its opening great.

**Issue:**
When hitting "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/", server just stops. No error and nothing happens. I don't understand that why I am not being able to hit the url.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Server state while quitting:

```
C:\Users\Maha Waqar\PycharmProjects\DjangoSites>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 09, 2020 - 21:40:44
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'DjangoSites.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[09/Mar/2020 21:41:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16351

C:\Users\Maha Waqar\PycharmProjects\DjangoSites>
```

My folder hirearchy:

```
DjangoSites //root folder

->DjangoSites

->mysite //current app I am working in
```

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` make sure you not only make the migration file, but you also apply them. Although I'm surprised there's no error message.

Comment: 1) I'm assuming you made both the project, and the app. 
2) Do an initial migration right after you make the project and the app
3) Make your 2 new models in the app models.py file
4) Make migrations
5) Migrate

Comment: What are your Django and python versions?

Comment: @dfundako see edit

Comment: @Hajar python 3.7, django 3.0.4

Comment: Try to upgrade to python 3.8 and see if it works.

Comment: @Hajar The django docs say Django 3 supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8

Comment: Yes! But I encountered a similar problem before when creating superusers and things only worked when I upgraded python.

Comment: What is the output of `echo %errorlevel%` after `runserver` exits?

Comment: And what is exact python version? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)

Comment: I am not quite sure from reading the post: Does the server really stops working or are you just not able to reach the admin site?

Comment: @Chris server just quits, as shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug and can be fixed by upgrade to python 3.8. 
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31092