# Asking Python what version I am using

Tags: python

Python has a version 2 and version 3. What code do I use to ask Python what version I am using in the module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)

Comment: From the command line:  `python --version`.  From inside Python: `import sys` then `sys.version`.

Comment: In particular, if you only care about the major version, you can use `sys.version_info.major`

Answer (score 0):

Use sys.version_info:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

The library is available for Python 3 and Python 2.

If you need to retrieve details about the OS, you can use `platform`

```
platform.python_version()

Returns the Python version as string 'major.minor.patchlevel'.
```

Comment: If you're printing it, just use `sys.version`, which is already formatted as a string.