# Does pandas DataFrame.to_sql work in ipynb files?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to import a `pd_DF` to `SQL` using a `file.ipynb` but it throws an error. If I try the same in a `file.py` it does work...

The error appears in the next line:

```
df2_imputed.to_sql('BBM_DATA', con=engine, index=False, if_exists= 'replace')
```

The error is:

> 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace''

At first, I thought it might be the NaN values inside de DF, but the DF has no `NAN` values now...

Can someone please help?
Is it possible to work with SQL in .ipynb files ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html I have it working to a SQLite db.  Could you share more of your code to see what the error is?

Comment: Yes, to_sql does work in ipynb files. I've used it.

Comment: If same code with same data does not work in Jupyter notebook (.ipynb) and regular script (.py), then issue must be environment: different Python version or pandas version, etc. Please compare versions of [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093322/1422451) and pandas/sqlalchemy versions and report back (do not assume anything).