# Check if python version is compatible with script before executing

Tags: python

I have a Python script that has been written using in Python 2.7. However it will be deployed to a number of different servers, some of which are running Python 2.4. In this case I am happy for the script to simply not run on the servers running Python 2.4. Is there a way I can do this in my Python script or would it be best to put a wrapper around the script?

I have tried doing this:

```
if sys.version_info[0] < 2.7:
    raise Exception("Python 2.7 or a more recent version is required.")
```

However because Python compiles the code before running it fails during compile when it hits part of the script that does not work in 2.4.

Comment: What about just not deploying to the servers that don't support Python 2.7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)

Comment: Your servers are in desperate need of an upgrade. Very strong advice to upgrade to Python 3.6+. Python 2.7 reached [EOL one year ago](https://endoflife.date/python), and Python 2.4 .. well, far too long ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.version_info[0]` is the major version only. So, it'll be `2` for all python 2.x versions. You're looking for `sys.version_info[1]`, with the minor version:

```py
# check for python 2
if sys.version_info[0] != 2:
    raise Exception("Please use Python 2")
# check for 2.7+
if sys.version_info[1] < 7:
    raise Exception("Please use Python 2.7+")
```

Alternatively, for more descriptive naming, you can use `sys.version_info.major` instead of `sys.version_info[0]` and `sys.version_info.minor` instead of `sys.version_info[1]`.

Also, make sure you add this near the top of your script so there are no incompatibilities before the line is hit and the exception is raised.

If your code uses incompatible syntax, then you should put the non-version checking code in a main function in a separate file, then import that after the check so that Python doesn't try to parse it.