# Any way to include based on Python version

Tags: python, include

I need to detect Python version and execute code just for this version.

I want to use one file for each version of Python.

Comment: Related: [How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093322/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sys.version_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version_info).

```
import sys
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
if PY3:
   # execute code for python 3
   import file_you_want_for_py3
else:
   # execute code for python 2
   import file_you_want_for_py2
```

Comment: Python 4 will be a thing some day, so it'd be better to do `elif sys.version_info[0] == 2; import file_you_want_for_py2; else: #error`

Comment: this will work only for 2.0 (2000) and newer, try to find a better solution

Comment: Use [`sys.version_info`][1] (since 2.0 in 2000). Proper reference is https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.version_info and not https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version_info!

Answer (score 2):

If you're not sure which version of a **module** might be available, you can use a try/except:

```
try:
    import new_shiny_module as module
except ImportError:
    import old_rusty_module as module
```

Answer (score 0):

the best and easiest way is to use [`tox`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) like python library.