# Using isnumeric in both Python2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unicode

Working on an application that has a function that takes in a value and I am trying to see if it is an `int`, `float` or `string`. After doing some looking online I found `isnumeric()` and `isdigit()` to cover both int and float scenarios and string is default.

Brilliant... problem solved :)

Well not quite! Because this app supports Python versions `2.7.15`, `3.4.8`, `3.5.5`, `3.6.6` and I learned that for Python 2 isnumeric and isdigit works on unicode while Python 3 it works on strings.

So I have my CI passing the tests for Python 3 but failing for Python 2 :(

Is there a way to check what version of Python is being ran dynamically and from there use the correct implementation of the functions?

Comment: `sys.version` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)

Comment: I prefer the `sys.version.major` if it's simply a difference between 2.xx vs 3.xx

Comment: @Iron Fist yes, it helps alright. Glad to see there's a way to get the version but have to slot it nicely into the code. Cheers for the help

Comment: Be careful with `isdigit` and `isnumeric`: in addition to `0`-`9`, both functions also consider special Unicode characters as digits, such as `⑥` [U+2465 CIRCLED DIGIT SIX](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/2465)...

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` on strings also with Python 2.x.
Second you can try to convert a variable to `float` and `int` and see if the action throws exception.

```
for x in ['aa', '2.3', '4']:
  try:
    x = int(x)
    print x, ' is integer'
    continue
  except:
    pass    

  try:
    x = float(x)
    print x, 'is float'
    continue
  except:
    pass

  print x, 'is string'



aa is string
2.3 is float
4  is integer
```

Answer (score 0):

For easy cross-version portability of unicode methods, you need to set `unicode`  to be an alias of `str` on Python 3.

```
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    # Python 3
    unicode = str

def isnumeric(s):
    return unicode(s).isnumeric()
```