# when running my coder in terminal of vscode it says my variable is undefined

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-2.x

I wrote a simple piece of code in VScode but when I run it in the terminal an error pops up saying the variable is not defined. however when I manually press the run code button the code runs without any errors.

The code:

```python
name = input("what is your name? ")
print("hello,", name)
```

the error message:

```
$ python hello.py
what is your name? ted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input("what is your name? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ted' is not defined
```

Comment: Please post your code, avoid links to images of code.

Comment: Please add code and error message as text, not as a screenshot. Concerning your problem: You try to run your code with Python 2. `input` is different in Python 2. You can even say that it's dangerous in Python 2. You might need to use `python3` to start your script.

Comment: Try using `python3 hello.py` instead of `python hello.py`

Comment: thanks that seemed to work. But why was python hello.py working before but not now

Comment: A Python 2 interpreter is running the code at the bottom with the error message. For Python 2 use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: on Mac the default `python` command is Python2

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple python versions installed on your machine, and your computer's default python version should be `python2` (perhaps related to system environment variables). You can check the version with `py -V`.

It is recommended that you use a virtual environment and keep only one python version in each virtual environment. When you select an interpreter ( **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **P** --> **Python: Select Interpreter**), the new terminal ( **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **`** ) will automatically activate the virtual environment.

Virtual environments are very useful for you to use a specific version of the interpreter and a specific package.

> To prevent such clutter, developers often create a virtual environment for a project. A virtual environment is a folder that contains a copy (or symlink) of a specific interpreter. When you install into a virtual environment, any packages you install are installed only in that subfolder. When you then run a Python program within that environment, you know that it's running against only those specific packages.

*How to create a virtual environment:*

1. Create Virtual Environment

   ```
   python -m venv <name_of_envirnment>
   ```
2. Activate Virtual Environment

   ```
   <name_of_envirnment>\scripts\activate
   ```

official documentation: [Create a virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment)