# Format text output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def formatWords(words):
  result = "Word List:\tWord Count:\n"
  for i in words:
    result += i + ":\t" + str(words.count(i)) + "\n"
  return result
```

words is just an array of strings.

I am supposed to get an output of

[image: Desired Output]

I get the output of

[image]

How do I format the string to look like the first picture?

Comment: Several dups of this question, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103052/python-string-formatting-columns-in-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the string method [`ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```
result += (i+':').ljust(20) + str(words.count(i)) + '\n'
```

`20` is the total size of that string, padded by however many spaces are needed to end up with that size.

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1:**

```
row_format = "{:<15}" * 2
rows = [('word list:', 'word_count'),
        ('brown', 1),
        ('dog', 1)]
for row in rows:
    print row_format.format(*row)
```

output:

```
word list:     word_count     
brown          1              
dog            1
```

**Example 2:**

```
row_format = "{:<15}{:^15}"
rows = [('word list:', 'word_count'),
        ('brown', 1),
        ('dog', 1)]
for row in rows:
    print row_format.format(*row)
```

output:

```
word list:       word_count   
brown                 1       
dog                   1
```

[Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)gives more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use `format` function.

```
result += "{:<20}{:<30}\n".format(i, words.count(i))
```