# delimiting a df output from mlxtend - association_rules in Python

Tags: python, apriori

I'm working with the [association_rules](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/association_rules/) from mlxtend package in python.

The resulting output is in a df and the antecedants/consequents columns can have a number of results separated by commas.

Here is the code used to generate the output:

`rules = association_rules(frequent_items, metric='lift',min_threshold=0.5)`

this results with the following headers:

`antecedants` `consequents` `antecedent support` `consequent support` `support` `confidence` `lift` `leverage` `conviction`

So with the column with the antecedants (also with the consequents) can have more than one result in the column as seen below:

`Antecedants
(SKU1, SKU2, SKU3)
(SKU1, SKU2)
(SKU1)
(SKU1, SKU2, SKU3, SKU4)`

However, I want to delimit based on the commas and extended the existing df with more columns

Desired output:

`antecedants     antecedants2     antecedants3     antecedants4
 SKU1            SKU2             SKU3
 SKU1            SKU2
 SKU1
 SKU1            SKU2             SKU3             SKU4`

I've tried using this line of code -
`rules['antecedants'].str.split(',', expand=True)` - but I get a bunch of NaNs as a result.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated - new to Python.

Comment: Can you post your code? 
in general- take a look here, seem like what you need- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103052/python-string-formatting-columns-in-line

Comment: The link you provided is for formatting. I'm trying to split a column with potentially a list of skus (separated by commas) into their own column.