# Get the Value of Column in all the rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to groupie my data based on Year and Month name but the year is getting reflected only in one column. I am trying to get it along all the rows:

```
three_month_t_bill_df['observation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(three_month_t_bill_df['observation_date'])


three_month_t_bill_df['Month_Number'] = three_month_t_bill_df['observation_date'].dt.month
three_month_t_bill_df['Year'] = three_month_t_bill_df['observation_date'].dt.year
result = three_month_t_bill_df['observation_date'].dt.month_name

three_month_t_bill_df['Month_Name'] = three_month_t_bill_df['Month_Number'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_name[x])

three_month_t_bill_df_monthly = three_month_t_bill_df.groupby(['Year', 'Month_Name']).agg("mean")
```

I am getting the following result:

```
1986    April   6.0625  4.0
        August  5.5780  8.0
        December    5.5100  12.0

... ... ... ...
2021    May 0.0175  5.0
        November    0.0525  11.0
        October 0.0500  10.0
        September   0.0425  9.0
```

The desired result is:

```
1986    April   6.0625  4.0
1986    August  5.5780  8.0
1986    December    5.5100  12.0
```

Comment: I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103052/string-formatting-columns-in-line

Comment: you're just missing a `reset_index`

Comment: use as_index=False parameter in the groupby