# Python function to print two strings evenly separated

Tags: python

I'm wanting a python function like this:

```
printSeperated("leftString", "rightString", screenWidth)
```

That would output:

```
leftString                    |                        rightString
```

Such that the "|" delimiter is at the midpoint of the screen.

I've tried:

```
def printSeperated(str1, str2, w = 20):
  print(str1.ljust(w), "|".center(w), str2.rjust(w))
```

But this does not keep the delimiter at the center of the screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting: Columns in line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103052/string-formatting-columns-in-line)

Comment: The default sep option, space, makes the result. Please use string concatination, '+' , instead of ','.  `print(str1.ljust(w) + "|".center(w) + str2.rjust(w))`

Comment: The question referenced by @Joe is helpful, but I continue to struggle if the left string is longer than the specified width... it seems there is no way to always force the delimiter to always be in the middle of the screen.

Comment: As mentioned here, you can't operate with the *screen* width, all you can do is operate the number and position of symbols. So you ARE able to keep the delimiter in the exact position as per the number of symbols counting from the left of the buffer. But you can't tell the separator to stay exactly in the middle of the screen as the graphics output device.

Comment: Just adding a comment, that its probably better to use a table printing library instead of doing this manually

Answer (score -1):

`print` doesn't know anything about the screen/terminal width. You probably have to use something like the [Curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) library.