# How to set precision without rounding?

Tags: python

I have big integers in database (numeric(24,0)). And I want to convert this number to "human readable" format. I have function:

```
def from_int(value, precision):
    fprec = "%." + str(precision) + "f"
    return fprec % (Decimal(value) * (Decimal(10)**(-1*precision)))
```

And it works:

```
from_int(1000000, 6)
'1.000000'
from_int(1000000, 8)
'0.01000000'
from_int(1000000, 12)
'0.000001000000'
from_int(1000000, 2)
'10000.00'
```

but for:

```
from_int(19999999999999999, 2)
'200000000000000.00'
```

How to set precision without rounding?

Comment: I think you are using `precision` wrong. It’s more a `numberOfDecimalPlaces` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting with `%f` converts the number to floating point losing precision. Instead use `str`:

```
def from_int(value, precision):
    return str(Decimal(value) * Decimal(10)**(-precision))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the %f construct that expects a float. So even if you compute everything in decimal, you have a nasty float conversion at the end => so the rounding issue. I think you could just write :

```
def from_int(value, precision):
    return str((Decimal(value) * (Decimal(10)**(-1*precision))))
```

I tested it on your values and it gives correct results.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a string representation, you may be able to get away with something like this:

```
>>> ('%%.%df' % 2) % 2.445
'2.44'
```

so in your original code:

```
def from_int(value, precision):
    return ('%%.%df' % precision) % value
```

EDIT:

To deal with precision issue, it's indeed simpler to use `Decimal` type, and the `quantize` method:

```
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(19999999999999999)
>>> prec = 2
>>> str(d.quantize(decimal.Decimal(10) ** -prec))
'19999999999999999.00'
>>>
```

ref: [How can I format a decimal to always show 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/python-how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

EDIT: Using the `Decimal` type, you can shift decimal places without rounding:

```
>>> str(d * (decimal.Decimal(10) ** -prec))
'199999999999999.99'
```

Comment: Yes but I want to get 199999999999999.99, not 19999999999999999.00

Comment: @Nips: Edited to add that part.