# Why is python rounding this value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I run the following code:

```
print math.pi, "******", 3.141592653589793
```

it outputs:

```
3.14159265359 ****** 3.14159265359
```

Why is the value being rounded?  If I want a more precise value for Pi how would I go about getting it?

Comment: probably it's just `print` that limits the number of decimal places in display. How about `"{0:.15f}".format(pi)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format a decimal to always show 2 decimal places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> print '%d'%math.pi
3
>>> print '%f'%math.pi
3.141593
>>> print '%.10f'%math.pi
3.1415926536
>>> print '%.20f'%math.pi
3.14159265358979311600
>>> print '%.30f'%math.pi
3.141592653589793115997963468544
```

You could use one of the above to get more digits after the comma printed. When doing calculations, Python use all the digits, but when printing them, Python uses either the default number of digits after comma, or the specified number of digits.

Your hardcoded number may get more digits when printed like this:

```
>>> print '%.20f'%3.141592653589793
3.14159265358979311600
```

As you can see the numbers are not 100% equals, the last digits are different. Is if given by the way floating point number are represented in computer memory.

Comment: Ahhh - that was totally it.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't happen to know if there is a way to set this globally do you?  So that I don't have to do it with every print statement?

Comment: I do not know. But my intuition says: it is not possible. Personally I always explicitly specify the number of digits after the comma for float numbers, it is safer like this. We should get used with the fact that print displays a representation of the object (i.e. of the float number) and not the object itself.