# Python format function: 1 decimal place

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
'{0:n}'.format(0/10.0)
```

which evaluates to

```
0
```

I want it to evaluate to

```
0.0
```

That is, there should always be 1 decimal place. What is the correct format for this?

Thanks.

Comment: round(floatval, decimalplaces)

Comment: `'{0:.1f}'.format(0/10.0)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940627/2308683 (change 2 to a 1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
print('{0:3.1f}'.format(0/10.0))  # '0.0'
```

`f` for [fixed-point notation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language); `3` for the total number of places to be reserved for the whole string, `1` for the decimal places.

if your number is too big to fit into the 3 reserved spaces, the string will use more space:

```
print('{0:3.1f}'.format(10.0))  # '10.0'; 4 places
```

---

with a more recent python version you can use f-strings (i put the value in a variable for more legibility)

```
x= 0/10.0
print('f{x:3.1f}')
```

Comment: Problem with this is, the docs say that n "uses the current locale setting to insert the appropriate number separator characters." My format string needs to be localized properly.

Comment: `f` is actually a float presentation type which stands for 'fixed-point notation'. [See the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: @daviewales ah, yes, that is correct. will update the answer. thanks!

Comment: To clarify: "if your number is too big to fit into the 3 reserved spaces, the string will use more space" applies to places to the left of the decimal point but not to the right: `print('{0:3.1f}'.format(10.3456)) # 10.3` but `print('{0:3.1f}'.format(10000.3456)) # 10000.3`. This is due to the `.1` configuration being a fixed number of decimal places.

Comment: @NeilG oh, i thought this was obvious... feel free to edit my answer if you feel that is not really clear.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [24]: "{0:.1f}".format(0)
Out[24]: '0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the data to float you the decimal .
a= 1.0 # "a" is a float
a= 1   # "a" is now a integer

try that :)