# Why is the Django decimal max_digits validation failing with strange behaviour?

Tags: python, django

I have a model field `full_time_equivalent`:

```
full_time_equivalent = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=5,
    decimal_places=2,
    default=100,
    validators=[
        MinValueValidator(Decimal(0)),
        MaxValueValidator(Decimal(100))
    ]
)
```

To ensure that the validators fire I have override `save` with:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Run validations
    self.full_clean()
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

With the following test:

```
    project2_membership = ProjectMembership(
        user=self.new_user,
        project=project2,
        is_project_manager=False,
        full_time_equivalent=10.01
    )
```

When I step into the validation the following value is shown and respective error:

```
Decimal('10.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625')


django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: 
{'full_time_equivalent': ['Ensure that there are no more than 5 digits in total.']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: had a look at the [django-code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/399a8db33b14a1f707912ac48a185fb0a1204913/django/db/models/base.py)...what happens if you only call `self.clean()`? Just want to figure out where's this issue coming from.

Comment: Looks like a floating point issue. If it is, then it is a bug either in the django validator (but it uses ``Decimal`` type which should not have such issues) or in your class getting the ``10.01`` argument.

Comment: I guess you may need to add some rounding. In the python shell, when I type `print(Decimal(10.01))`, I get  `10.009999...` like you do.

Comment: I wonder if this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places 

`Decimal(10.01).quantize(Decimal(10) ** -2))`

Comment: Note that by calling `full_clean()` in `save()`, you'll end up running the validation twice in places that use model forms like the Django admin.

Comment: Ah, perhaps these validations can just be handled on the form? What is your opinion?

Comment: It's a trade off. It's good to avoid the duplicated validation in `save()`. But there's a chance that you might write a view and forget to call `full_clean()` before saving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decimal value `10.01` can't be expressed exactly as a float. When the value is converted to a decimal, you end up with `Decimal('10.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625')`, which is very nearly equal to `Decimal('10.01')`, but fails your `max_digits` validation.

You can prevent the error by using the string `'10.01'` or the decimal `Decimal('10.01')` in your test.

```
from decimal import Decimal

project2_membership = ProjectMembership(
    user=self.new_user,
    project=project2,
    is_project_manager=False,
    full_time_equivalent=Decimal('10.01')
)
```