# Python string formatting - combine named placeholder and float formatter for the same argument?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, formatting, string-formatting

In Python is possible to combine 2 followings concepts - named arguments and float formatting?

`'{0:.2f}'.format(pi)`

and

`'{first} {last}'.format(first='Hodor', last='Hodor!')`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940627/2230844

https://pyformat.info/#named_placeholders

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'{value:.2f}'.format(value=pi)
```

Comment: haha, just found at the bottom of the article: https://pyformat.info/#param_align

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> pi=3.14159
>>> print('{number:.2f}'.format(number=pi))
3.14
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Also worth mentioning is the fstrings answer: `print(f'{pi:.2f}')`