# How to write a program to print a floating number up to 2 decimal places using string formatting in Pyhton

Tags: python

I have this, but it does not work

```
number = int(input("Please give the number"))
print("Formatted Number: " + "{:.2f}".format(number));
print(number)
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What's the expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I format a decimal to always show 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of "int" you can use "eval" [more about eval](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-eval-built-in-function-601f87db191)

```
  number = eval(input("Please give the number"))
  print("Formatted Number: " + "{:.2f}".format(number));
  print(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error with this code because you are trying to convert the float value to **int** while taking input. If you want to take a float input from user then round the value as you want and turn it into a **string** value then you can use the code provided below:

```
number = float(input("Please give the number"))  # take input as float

print("Formatted Number: " + str(round(number,2)))  # round upto 2 and convert to string
```

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for or not.

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax that you mentioned

```
print("Formatted Number: " + "{:.2f}".format(number));
```

will work but you cant round **int** number.

Remove "int" from `number = int(input("Please give the number"))`

and replace it with "float" `number = float(input("Please give the number"))`