# How can I return a list with only up to the second decimal place python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following list of values:

```
      value_list=[2.5655665, 3.151498745, 3.1, 0.9999999999]
```

I need to update this list keeping only to the second decimal place. I would like the result to be:

```
      print(value_list)

      [2.56, 3.15, 3.1, 0.99]
```

I tried to keep only to the second decimal place using the round() method passing parameter 2. As follows:

```
     value_list.round(2)
```

But, the error message appears:

```
     AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'round'
```

I made an attempt by transforming the value_list to the array type, like this:

```
     import numpy as np
     value_list = np.array(value_list).round(2)
```

This way it works, but it returns an array and I needed the return to be of type list. How can I return a list with only up to the second decimal place?

Comment: If you want to keep the values as floats, there's no way to keep only a specific number of decimal places. You can *round* float values, but the nearest rounded float value may still contain more decimal places than you like. You'd need to convert them to other data types, like a string or `Decimal`, to have a say about the *exact* formatting.

Comment: Most math and element-wise functions have to be applied one by one to lists.  I like list comprehensions, but `map` also works.  Or for chains of operations consider generators and `itertools`.  There are only 11 list methods, so it's not hard to remember them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map and apply whatever function you see fit:

```
value_list=[2.5655665, 3.151498745, 3.1, 0.9999999999]
value_rounded = list(map(lambda x: float(format(x, '.2f')), value_list))
value_truncated = list(map(lambda x: float(str(x)[:str(x).index('.')+3]), value_list))
print(value_rounded)
print(value_truncated)
```

Outputs for both cases:

```
[2.57, 3.15, 3.1, 1.0]
[2.56, 3.15, 3.1, 0.99]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
value_list=[2.5655665, 3.151498745, 3.1, 0.9999999999]
my_formatted_list = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in value_list ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point values are not necessarily represented as rounded but you can print them this way:

```
value_list = [2.5655665, 3.151498745, 3.1, 0.9999999999]
for v in value_list:
   print("{:.2f}".format(v))
```

You can also use `Decimal` type to ensure the values are rounded: [How can I format a decimal to always show 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Then, you can create a list of values rounded to the second decimal place:

```
value_list = [2.5655665, 3.151498745, 3.1, 0.9999999999]
values_rounded = []
for v in value_list:
   values_rounded.append(v.round(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#decimal.Decimal).  First you need to set the precision in the context:

```
from decimal import getcontext
getcontext().prec=2
```

Then convert:

```
value_list = [Decimal(i) for i in value_list]
```

If you print the list, you will still see all the other digits:

```
[Decimal('2.56556650000000008304823495564050972461700439453125'),
 Decimal('3.151498745000000045735077947028912603855133056640625'),
 Decimal('3.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625'),
 Decimal('0.9999999998999999917259629000909626483917236328125')]
```

However, for mathematical operations, your precision will be respected; e.g.

```
[i -1 for i in value_list]
```

returns

```
[Decimal('1.6'), Decimal('2.2'), Decimal('2.1'), Decimal('-1.0E-10')]
```