# I am implementing pset3 Felipe’s Taqueria in cs50p; but I have noticed something odd in the variables after running debug

Tags: python, cs50

My code seems to work perfectly except it output a float with only one decimal place instead of two as per dictionary created.

The dictionary gave each item a price e.g "Taco": 3.00; surprisingly when I run debug dictionary has different value e.g "Taco": 3.0 instead of 3.00

I would like to know why it is behaving this way.

here is my code:

```
# make a dictionary
dict = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
}
# with a while loop prompt for item and add item value until user input exit
total = 0
while True:
    try:
        item = input("Item: ").strip().title()
        for order in dict:
            if order == item:
                total = total + (dict[order])
                print(f"${total}")
    except EOFError:
        break
```

I expected my program to output a total of two decimal places instead of just one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I format a decimal to always show 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Thank you; but what I wanted to know is why the output Is different from the values of the dictionary?

Comment: Because you're storing a float number. Python only stores the minimum float/decimal precision necessary for any given number. `float(4.00) = 4.0` because the extra zero provides no extra information about the number. So if you want it stored with two decimals, store it as a string. If you want it stored as a number, then you have to format the output string with the extra precision you want

Answer (score 0):

use
`print(f'Total: ${total:.2f}')`

test it on python terminal:

```
x = 12.3
>>> print(f'{x:.2f}')
12.30
>>> print(f'{x:.3f}')
12.300
>>> print(f'{x:.4f}')
12.3000
>>> print(f'{x:.5f}')
12.30000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).