# Having trouble formatting my decimals

Tags: python

I need my outputs to be in 3 decimals

```
def main():

    n = eval(input("Enter the number of random steps: "))
    t = eval(input("Enter the number of trials: "))

    pos = 0
    totalPosition = 0
    totalSum = 0
    L = list()

    import random
    A = [-1, 1]

    for x in range(t):
        pos = 0
        for y in range(n):
            step = random.choice(A)
            pos += step


        totalPosition += abs(pos)
        totalSum += pos**2

    pos1 = totalPosition/t
    totalSum /= t
    totalSum = totalSum**0.5


    print("The average distance from the starting point is a %.3f", % pos1)
    print("The RMS distance from the starting point is %.3f", % totalSum)

main()
```

I keep getting syntax errors whether I try to use both the '%' character and the {0:.3f} .format(pos1) method. Anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `eval` for this, use direct type conversion: `int(input('...'))`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `,` in print function just `%` is enough for example:

```
print("The RMS distance from the starting point is %.3f", % totalSum)
                                                        ^ remove this ,
```

like:

```
print("The RMS distance from the starting point is %.3f" % totalSum)
```

Comment: @YotamKasznik Your welcome Yotam, I believe you will like this to read this [**String formatting in Python**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python) ... interesting

Answer (score 1):

For string interpolation, you need to put the `%` operator right behind the format string:

```
print ("The average distance from the starting point is a %.3f" % pos1)
```

it is a bit more obvious if you use the more modern `format` way:

```
print ("The average distance from the starting point is a {:.3f}".format(pos1))
```

Comment: everytime I do the {:.3f} way, I get syntax errors and it highlights the period before format

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. I'm not too good with python to say the least haha but im learning. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @YotamKasznik Yotam preferable way to say thanks on stackoverflow is by voting-up. Thomas given a nice way ... Give it a try again!, its more friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You have commas between the string literal and the % sign. Remove those.

```
print("The average distance from the starting point is a %.3f" % pos1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `print` and formatting confused:

```
print("The average distance from the starting point is a %.3f" % pos1)
```

You should really prefer the new style formatting though:

```
print("Whatever {:.3f}".format(pos1))
```

Or, if you really wanted:

```
print("Whatever", format(pos1, '.3f'))
```