# Is there any way to use variables in multiline string in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-interpolation

So I have this as part of a mail sending script:

```
try:
    content = ("""From: Fromname <fromemail>
    To: Toname <toemail>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-type: text/html
    Subject: test

    This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

    <b>This is HTML message.</b>
    <h1>This is headline.</h1>
    """)
```

...

```
    mail.sendmail('from', 'to', content)
```

And I'd like to use different subjects each time (let's say it's the function argument).

I know there are several ways to do this.

However, I am also using ProbLog for some of my other scripts (a probabilistic programming language based in Prolog syntax).
As far as I know, the only way to use ProbLog in Python is through strings, and if the string is broke in several parts; example = ("""string""", variable, """string2"""), as well as in the email example above, there's no way I can make it work.

I actually have a few more scripts where using variables in multiline strings could be useful, but you get the idea.

Is there any way to make this work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do.

Comment: You appear to want a multi-line `String`, not a multi-line comment. Using a variable in a comment wouldn't make any sense - comments aren't executed.

Comment: Python doesn't _have_ multi-line comments. Triple-quoted strings are **not** comments.

Comment: That's right. Sorry. Multiline strings. I'm new into python. I just didn't thought about it.

Comment: This question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355 ... this question is not a duplicate because the other question does not refer to using multi-line strings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the `.format` method:

```
content = """From: Fromname <fromemail>
    To: {toname} <{toemail}>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-type: text/html
    Subject: {subject}

    This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

    <b>This is HTML message.</b>
    <h1>This is headline.</h1>
"""
mail.sendmail('from', 'to', content.format(toname="Peter", toemail="p@tr", subject="Hi"))
```

Once that last line gets too long, you can instead create a dictionary and unpack it:

```
peter_mail = {
    "toname": "Peter",
    "toemail": "p@tr",
    "subject": "Hi",
}
mail.sendmail('from', 'to', content.format(**peter_mail))
```

---

As of Python 3.6, you can also use multi-line f-strings:

```
toname = "Peter"
toemail = "p@tr"
subject = "Hi"
content = f"""From: Fromname <fromemail>
    To: {toname} <{toemail}>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-type: text/html
    Subject: {subject}

    This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

    <b>This is HTML message.</b>
    <h1>This is headline.</h1>
"""
```