# Replace each occurrence of sub-strings in the string with randomly generated values

Tags: python, string, substring

I am having strings like:

```
"What is var + var?"
"Find the midpoint between (var,var) and (var,var)"
```

I want to change the each occurrence of `var`s in the above sentences to the random different integers. My current code code is:

```
question = question.replace("var",str(random.randint(-10,10)))
```

This only made all the integers into the same randomly genererated number, For example;

```
"Find the midpoint between (5,5) and (5,5)"
```

As I'm aware that `for` loops cannot be used on a string, how is it possible to change the substring "var" to different values rather than that single generated number?

Comment: (1) Strings in Python are immutable, you cannot alter them. (2) [Read about string formatting](https://pyformat.info/), this probably would help you ask the right question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) to achieve this as:

```
import random

my_str = "Find the midpoint between (var,var) and (var,var)"

var_count = my_str.count("var") # count of `var` sub-string
format_str = my_str.replace('var', '{}') # create valid formatted string

# replace each `{}` in formatted string with random `int`
new_str = format_str.format(*(random.randint(-10, 10) for _ in range(var_count)))
```

where `new_str` will hold something like:

```
'Find the midpoint between (6,-10) and (-5,2)'
```

**Suggestion**: It is better to use `'{}'` instead of `'var'` in the original string (as python performs formatting based on `{}`). Hence, in the above solution you may skip the `.replace()` part.

---

References related to *string formatting*:

- [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)
- [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Comment: except that you have to _store_ the random values and sort them, or noone can check that your answer is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to make it easier:

```
pattern  = "Find the midpoint between (%s, %s) and (%s, %s)"
question = pattern % (str(1), str(2), str(3.0), str(4))
print(question)
>>> Find the midpoint between (1, 2) and (3.0, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting, like so:

```
"What is {} + {}?".format(random.randint(-10,10), random.randint(-10,10))
```

and:

```
four_random_numbers = [random.randint(-10, 10) for _ in range(4)]
"Find the midpoint between ({}, {}) and ({}, {})".format(*four_random_numbers)
```

You could easily re-write it as a function returning n-random numbers to use in your questions.