# How to add strings here

Tags: python

I have values stored in variables which i am trying to append in payload but it's not taking,please let me know how to do it

```
 r=(issues["fields"]["resolution"]["name"])
        #print (r)
        p=(issues["fields"]["customfield_13709"])
        #print (p)
        s=(issues["fields"]["summary"])
        #print(s)
        k=(issues["key"])
        #print(k)
        a=(issues["fields"]["assignee"]["name"])
        #print (a)    
    payload = "{\r\n\t\"fields\":{\r\n\"project\":{\"key\":\"SSETOPS\"},\r\n\"summary\":\"s\",\r\n\"description\":\"k+s\",\r\n\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Task\"},\r\n\"customfield_12610\":{\"value\":\"High\"},\r\n\"components\":[{\"name\":\"Other\"}],\r\n\"assignee\":{\"name\":\"rahsingh\"}\r\n}}"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python

Comment: i tried formatting but i want to get the value stored in variable s to be printed in summary in payload but it is taking only s as character

Comment: We can't run this code as it stands. Edit your question to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: i have some value say k=1234 and s=this is description,in \r\n\"description\":\"k+s\".I want to print 1234 this is description but it is printing k+s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your code is that you have `s` and `s+k` inside the quotes and the interpreter treats it like a normal string not a variable. if you want to append 2 strings you need to use + operation.

```
strA = "this is string A"
strB =  "this is a string B + String A i,e " +strA
print(strB)
```

**output**

```
'this is a string B + String A i,e this is string A'
```

Here is how to append string to another string in your case:

```
s = "some summary" #Assumed some Values
k = "something else"

payload = "{\r\n\t\"fields\":{\r\n\"project\":{\"key\":\"SSETOPS\"},\r\n\"summary\":" +'\"'+ s +'\"'+ ",\r\n\"description\":" +'\"'+ k+" "+s +'\"'+ ",\r\n\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Task\"},\r\n\"customfield_12610\":{\"value\":\"High\"},\r\n\"components\":[{\"name\":\"Other\"}],\r\n\"assignee\":{\"name\":\"rahsingh\"}\r\n}}"
print(payload)
```

This is what i got as an **output** :

```
{
    "fields":{
"project":{"key":"SSETOPS"},
"summary":"some summary",
"description":"something else some summary",
"issuetype":{"name":"Task"},
"customfield_12610":{"value":"High"},
"components":[{"name":"Other"}],
"assignee":{"name":"rahsingh"}
}}
```

Comment: could you please help me in adding hyperlinks to a string,as i have some string which i need  to show but as a hyperlink with a web url

Comment: you want to add that string in payload ?

Comment: no not in payload,assume i have string google to output but it should be having hyperlink.When user clicks it,google website opens.I want to know how to create hyperlinks in python

Comment: that depends on your application, where do you want show this hyperlink e.g django /flask or some other web framework.

to add simple html tag we use this :`<a href="where/you/want/the/link/to/go">text of the link</a>`

Comment: id="http://ontrack-internal.mycompany.com/browse/%s"%(p) where p is the id.I need only the id to show up with the url

Comment: Could you help me with it?

Comment: i am sorry i didn't get your problem.it is still not very clear what you are asking. I would love to help. but i see to see the code . Maybe you can ask a new question here at SO with more details added

Comment: Suppose i have ID as TIC123 and i have to put hyperlink http://ontrack.com/browse/TIC123 as when i print id then TIC123 will have hyperlink and it opens on browser

Comment: If i want to add double quotes to summary and description,then how can i do that?

Comment: thanks a lot,Please could you let me know how to use href in python?

Comment: if you want to see href in console output . I am afraid that will not be possible.

Comment: just wanted to know how to show string output with web link in python,as by just clicking on output screen it will go to link

Comment: it doesn't work this way. you cannot make output screen print a hyperlink

Comment: no i want to add it in a string and send a mail with that string,everything is done.But i am unable to add hyperlink to the string