# how do I check for numbers in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I need to check if the numbers in gradescale is in my NxM matrix as a numpy array, if example the number 8 is in  my matrix, I would like to append the number to a empty list and the row number to another list
So how do i check if the number in my matrix isn't in gradescale, i have tried different types of loops, but they dont work.

```
 wrongNumber = []
 Rows = []
 gradeScale = np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])
 if there is a number i matrix which is not i gradeScale
     wrongNumber.append[number]
     Rows.append[rownumber]
print("the grade {} in line {} is out of range",format(wrongNumber), 
format(Rows))
```

Comment: So what seem to be the problem?

Comment: How do i find the numbers i my matrix, i cant figure out to make the right loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ndarray.shape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) to go through your rows.

```
for row in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for x in matrix[row]:
        if x not in gradeScale:
            wrongNumber.append(x)
            Rows.append(row)
```

In addition, you do not use `format` correctly. Your print statement should be

```
print("The grade {} in line {} is out of range".format(wrongNumber, Rows))
```

The following post has some more information on formatting [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python) .

### Example

```
import numpy as np

wrongNumber = []
Rows = []

matrix = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
gradeScale = [1,3,4,5,8]

for row in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for x in matrix[row]:
        if x not in gradeScale:
            wrongNumber.append(x)
            Rows.append(row)

print("The grades {} in lines {} (respectively) are out of range.".format(wrongNumber, Rows))
```

#### Output

```
The grades [2, 6, 7] in lines [0, 2, 3] (respectively) are out of range
```

Comment: This dosen't work it, i think i have to loop over my matrix instead somehow

Comment: Well, as you can see I checked it and it indeed works. What is the format of your matrix?

Comment: in the example wrong numbers instead should be [2,4] but if I use != instead of == would it mayby work

Comment: Ohh, I see you requested for the opposite.

Comment: Yes it will not work for the opposite case. I will try to update my answer.

Comment: @MelanieNielsen I have updated my answer. If this solves your question let us clean up this comment section.

Comment: Thanks it works now!
So in the first loop I loop over the rows in the matrix
and i the second loop I loop over the elements in the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a for loop with `enumerate()` is what you are looking for.

Example:

```
for rowNumber, number in enumerate(matrix)
    if number not in gradeScale:
        wrongNumber.append[number]
        Rows.append[rowNumber]
```