# Formatting HTML with Python

Tags: python, html

I want to format my html code in python.

My Python file is:

```
titles = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
html_text = """<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { border-collapse: collapse;}
        td { text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ff0000; border-style: dashed; font-size: 30px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="5px">
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html> % (titles[0], titles[1], titles[2], titles[3], titles[4])"""

f = open('temp.html', 'w')
f.write(html_text)
f.close()
```

I want to make those %s to be titles[0], titles[1], titles[2], titles[3], titles[4].

How can I make it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit: My bad didn't see the bottom of the scroll box

Comment: @Brandon The code, don't ya see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use some [template engine that mix logic into template](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating).

Example with [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/):

1. install with `pip install jinja2`

2 then the code would be:

```
html_text = """<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="5px">
        {% for title in titles %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{title}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>"""

from jinja2 import Template
titles = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
my_templ = Template(html_text)
with open('temp.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(my_templ.render(titles=titles))
```

Note that it is flexible to handle list of variable length.
Template engines are used in the web frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your format string. The first, as U9-Forward pointed out, is here:

```
</html> % (titles[0], titles[1], titles[2], titles[3], titles[4])"""
```

The `%` is an interpolation *operator* so it needs to go *between* the string and the data:

```
</html>""" % (titles[0], titles[1], titles[2], titles[3], titles[4])
```

The second error, apparent only after you fixed that one, is here:

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="5px">
```

When you use the `%` operator, the character `%` becomes special, so that `%s` does what you expect. But when that happens, `"100%"` isn't legal, because, as the error message told you, it puts an `unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 237`. You could have found this out for yourself in under a minute by putting your cursor at the beginning of the string and pressing right-arrow 237 times.

In this case, the `%` that you want to stay `%` must be doubled:

```
<table width="100%%" height="100%%" border="5px">
```

That gives

```
html_text = '''<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { border-collapse: collapse;}
        td { text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ff0000; border-style: dashed; font-size: 30px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%%" height="100%%" border="5px">
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>''' % (titles[0], titles[1], titles[2], titles[3], titles[4])
```

But the fundamental problem here is that Python `%`-strings are a formatting mini-language, and HTML is a formatting language, and so constructing HTML like this means you are programming in two languages simultaneously. The doublethink that this involves gives some experienced programmers a kick, but the rest of us are happier separating our concerns and dealing with one language at a time. Instead of `%`-strings, consider using `lxml` to construct your HTML. There is more of a learning curve (eased by an excellent [tutorial](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html)) but your code will be easier to write and maintain, and `lxml` will ensure your HTML is free of syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

`fstrings` is what cool kids use nowadays.

```
titles = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
html_text = f"""<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {{ border-collapse: collapse;}}
        td {{ text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ff0000; border-style: dashed; font-size: 30px; }}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="5px">
        <tr>
            <td>{titles[0]}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{titles[1]}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{titles[2]}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{titles[3]}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{titles[4]}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>"""


with open('temp.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_text)
```

You put variable in `{}` within a text, and your styles have to be escaped with double `{{}}`. Try it out.

Also, pythonic way of writing to a file is with a context manager. It handles closing without the need of `.close()` on an opened file.

Comment: It give me an error:  `</html>""" SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It works just fine, trust me. I run it here. Unless, of course, you work on Python 2.x. It has to be 3.x

Comment: Python 3.6+, to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You ended the string in the wrong place, so use the below as full code:

```
titles = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
html_text = '''<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { border-collapse: collapse;}
        td { text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ff0000; border-style: dashed; font-size: 30px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="5px">
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>''' % (titles[0], titles[1], titles[2], titles[3], titles[4])

f = open('temp.html', 'w')
f.write(html_text)
f.close()
```

So now you'll get your expected HTML file.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, but your code doesn't work. It gives me this error: `ValueError: unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 237`, and my HTML file isn't changed, too.

Comment: @HoseongJeon Error?

Comment: @HoseongJeon then type it yourself, don't use cut-n-paste... At least make some effort.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I agree with you, yeah.