# SyntaxError: invalid syntax "url = ("https://etherscan.io/address/%s"address)

Tags: python

This is my code for print: `"url = ("https://etherscan.io/address/%s"address)"` and i got SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My Python version is 3.7 and i'm new to python
I think %s is the problem, i'm not what replacement of that in Python 3.7

Comment: `url = "https://etherscan.io/address/%s" % address`  this is the way to do python string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = ("https://etherscan.io/address/%s" % address)
                                         ^
```

You're missing the % to assign the variable. Alternatively you can use other forms of string formatting:

Using `.format()`

`url = "https://etherscan.io/address/{}".format(address)`

Using `f` strings:

`url = f"https://etherscan.io/address/{address}"`

Comment: Why do you answer these kind of questions?

Comment: To help? It might seem trivial to experienced users..

Comment: oh it works! Thanks, coding in python is exciting.

Comment: You're welcome, and yes it is! :)

Comment: @MattB. Just flag as a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python

Comment: @MattB. I will close since i've got 3k, and  gold-python

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you meant, why *bother* haha. Ok thanks.

Comment: @MattB. I think you shall delete this... :-)

Comment: @MattB.  Might I also suggest: 
`url = "https://etherscan.io/address/{}".format(address)`? ;-)

Comment: Hmmm very excellent suggestion kind sir! :)

Comment: I would then suggest `url = f"https://etherscan.io/address/{address}"` as he's got 3.7 :P

Comment: It'll be very nice if you'd add those in your answer, sir! :)