# How to pass a variable into a bash command in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I have a Python script which selects a port at random and passes it to the bash command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import os

# Select a port at random
port = ['22', '23', '24']
selected_port = (random.choice(port))
# print 'selected_port

bashCommand = "ssh -p '${selected_port}' -i pi.rsa pi@192.168.1.xx"
os.system(bashCommand)
```

What is the correct way to pass `selected_port` variable to my `bashCommand`? Currently I'm getting a `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: `bashCommand = "ssh -p '{}' -i pi.rsa pi@192.168.1.xx".format(selected_port)`

Comment: Form the command string properly 

bashCommand = "ssh -p " + selected_port + " -i pi.rsa pi@192.168.1.xx"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone though above works in given specific scenario, it's not generating the identical string as single quotes are missing.

Comment: That's a fair point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of Python's string interpolation mechanisms:

```
bashCommand = "ssh -p '%s' -i pi.rsa pi@192.168.1.xx" % selected_port
```

or

```
bashCommand = "ssh -p '{}' -i pi.rsa pi@192.168.1.xx".format(selected_port)
```