# Executing .py with bash command but how to pass variables - Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG definition file where I use BashOperator to call a Python script:

```
with DAG(dag_id='test', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 1 * * *', catchup=False) as dag:

    # Instantiate tasks
    task_1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='tsk1',
        bash_command=f'python {PATH}/update_files.py'   
    )
```

update_files.py:

```
import wsclient

def function_one():
  ...
  return df

def function_two(df):
  ...
  return df_transformed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = WSClient("https://")
    if ws.do_login(usr, pws):
        raw_dataframe = function_one()
        transformed_dataframe = function_two(raw_dataframe )
        for record in transformed_dataframe.to_dict(orient='records'):
            ws.do_create('Clients', record)
```

usr and pws are username and passwords used for "https://". Currently, I store pws and usr as a variable in Airflow.

How can I extract Airflow variables and use them in my script? I found a few answers here but all of them are about passing params to PythonOperator, not BashOperator.

Comment: Can you do it in the DAG definition and pass them as command-line arguments? Then the python script can get them from `sys.argv`

Comment: It is a good point, I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772166/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-a-bash-command-in-python. is it what you had in mind?

Comment: That's doing it in Python. I don't know the equivalent in an Airflow DAG definition.

Comment: Does using the `env` keyword help? See the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html).