# Format string and write

Tags: python

I would like to save a file with formated text however, I don't know where to put my formatting command.

Here is my reproducible code:

```
start = "2008-12-08"
end = "2009-12-27"
template ="""- {start} + {end}:
    CycleCalendar:
        start_date: {start}
        start_type: Packing
        end_date: {end}
        end_type: unpacking
        max_duration: 720
    """

with open("conf.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(template)
```

I was thingiking about use `.format` however, don't know where to put it.

My question is unique because it is **using objects** for the formatting of the text

Thank you!

Comment: `template.format(start=start, end=end)` ?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: `.format()` is a string method, any string can call this method like this: `"string {}".format(1)`, also template can `template.format(start=start, end=end)`

Comment: @Christoffer python 3.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Comment: For 3.6+ you could just use `f"..{start}"`

Comment: `f.write(template.format(start=start))` is working. Great! I was using only the `f.write(template.format(start))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
start = "2008-12-08"
end = "2009-12-27"
template ="""- {start} + {end}:
    CycleCalendar:
        start_date: {start}
        start_type: Packing
        end_date: {end}
        end_type: unpacking
        max_duration: 720
    """

with open("conf.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(template.format(start=start, end=end))
```