# Using variable in an API request in Python

Tags: python, request, response

I would like to know how to use a variable in the following API call:

```
response=requests.get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/f3bc3bd870812cc013666f2bfb75b45d/50,1,2019-11-18T22:05:45+00:00')
```

instead of the random values 50 and 1 in this example, I would like to put my variables for latitude and longitude, integrated in a for loop. When I try this is not working and a 400 error happens. Is it a syntax error or is it impossible ? I read the whole [documentation](https://darksky.net/dev/docs#time-machine-request) of this API and nothing indicates that it's impossible.

[EDIT]Example of a try :

```
for i in range(0,precision):
    
    response=requests.get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/f3bc3bd870812cc013666f2bfb75b45d/latitude[i],longitude[i],2019-11-18T22:05:45+00:00')
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)  
    
    wind_speed[i]=json_data["currently"]["windSpeed"]
    wind_dir[i]=json_data["currently"]["windBearing"]
```

In this example for i=0, latitude[i]=51.4888 and longitude[i]=-3.16657

and here is the error message

```
  File "C:/Users/ab79/Documents/GPX WEATHER/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(json_data["currently"]["windSpeed"])

KeyError: 'currently'
```

Comment: *"But when I do this"* - when you do *what*? Give a [mcve].

Comment: can you give us an example of the lat/long coordinates you're trying?

Comment: Of course, I edited my question

Comment: Use an _f-string_? `f'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/f3bc3bd870812cc013666f2bfb75b45d/{latitude[i]},{longitude[i]},2019-11-18T22:05:45+00:00'`

Comment: It's not working :'(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
base_url = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/f3bc3bd870812cc013666f2bfb75b45d/{},{},2019-11-18T22:05:45+00:00'
url = base_url.format(latitude[i],longitude[i])
r = requests.get(url)

data = r.json()
```

You're running into an issue because you're trying to inject the variables directly into the url string. Try using a `.format()` (above) or an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) like this:

```
url = f'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/f3bc3bd870812cc013666f2bfb75b45d/{latitude[i]},{longitude[i]},2019-11-18T22:05:45+00:00'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
```

Comment: WORKED ! Thank you :D

Comment: @AntoineBerger you should also read the documentation for [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, i'll do it