# Create a string with single and double quotes

Tags: python, excel, string, dataframe, formula

I need to insert a formula into Excel using Python.  I am creating a dataframe and adding a column containing the formulas and then writing it into an Excel.

The formula has the format `'=HYPERLINK("#'"&F2&"'!A1",F2)'`

F2 is a variable and all other characters are constant.  I need to dynamically generate this string.

I tried doing `=HYPERLINK("#'"&F2&"'!A1",F2)` but it is not working and I got `'=HYPERLINK("#\'"&F2&"\'!A1",F2)'` which includes the back slash and the formula does not work.

How do I create a string like `'=HYPERLINK("#'"&F2&"'!A1",F2)'` ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might find this to be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/517372/13131172

Comment: You might want to use formatting. I'm not completely able to understand your needs, but you can surely try this. ```print('=HYPERLINK("#'"&{}&"'!A1")'.format('F2'))```.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Reference]
The method you used works with Python 3, i checked it with trinket.io

Comment: Thanks.  Same issue as the other answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making string dynamically. There are two things you can do.

1. `r'=HYPERLINK("#'"&F2&"'!A1",F2)'` r signifies raw string (if you are not using any variable).
2. If you are making string dynamically using other variables. Use formatted string.

   `var1= '"#'"&F2&"'!A1"'
   var2= 'F2'
   formula= f'=HYPERLINK({var1},{var2} )'`

> `print(formula)`
>
> `'=HYPERLINK("#&F2&!A1",F2 )'`

Comment: Thanks but print() behaves differently than when storing in a variable.  For example print('=HYPERLINK("#'+"'"+'"&F2&"'+"'!A1"+'",F2)') gives me the same output as yours.  But I need to store it in a variable and insert into a dataframe column.  When I do s = '=HYPERLINK("#'+"'"+'"&F2&"'+"'!A1"+'",F2)' , variable 's' has value '=HYPERLINK("#\'"&F2&"\'!A1",F2)'

Comment: Then this is not a problem with string creation.Looks like Pandas is adding an escape sequence when creating excel/CSV file. You need to provide file and code you are using to write an excel file. Plus you should upvote answer if you find it useful.