# I am new to programming and in this code there is an error I don't understand

Tags: python, time

The error says: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Add: 'int' and 'str' on line 39". What does this mean and how do i fix this?
Here is the code:

```
import time
TimeIsUp=0
print ("Timer")
h=int(input("Hours-"))
m=int(input("Minutes-"))
if m>59:
 while m>0 and m!=0:
  m-=60
  h+=1
 m+=60
 h-=1
s=int(input("Seconds-"))
if s>59:
 while s>0 and s!=0:
  s-=60
  m+=1
 s+=60
 m-=1
 while m>=0 and m!=0:
  m-=60
  h+=1
 m+=60
 h-=1
while TimeIsUp==0:
 s-=1
 if s<0 and m>0:
  s+=61
  m-=1
  if m<0 and h>0:
   m+=61
   h-=1
 else:
  if h>0:
   s+=61
   m+=59
   h-=1
  else:
   TimeIsUp==1
 print (h+":"+m+":"+s)
 time.sleep(1)
print ("Time's Up!")
```

The "time" import if from https://trinket.io/python (Because that is what im using to code Phython as a beginner).

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Full traceback please

Comment: btw You should prefer to use python3 which trinket.io does support.

Answer (score 5):

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Add: 'int' and 'str' on line 39". What does this mean

It means that on line #39 of your code, you're trying to add (the '+' operator) an integer and an string -  which doesn't make sense. Reading your code, this is obviously this line:

```
 print h+":"+m+":"+s
```

Note that strings implement the '+' operator as string concatenation, while ints implement it as (of course) addition.

> and how do i fix this?"

You could turn your ints into strings as mentionned in other comments or answers, but the proper solution here is to use string formatting operations:

```
print "{}:{}:{}".format(h, m, s)
```

or if you want to be more explicit

```
print "{hour}:{minutes}:{seconds}".format(hour=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)
```

`str.format()` will take care of necessary conversions etc, and also provides more advanced formatting operations (leading zeros for numerics etc).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to cast you integer values inside the print function. The reason is that the print function requires a string and Python does not auto-cast integers when are concatenated with strings:

```
print str(h) + ":" + str(m) + ":" + str(s)
```

Comment: btw there is no casting in python. What you have correctly used here is the `str()` function which *converts* other types to `str`.

Comment: @quamrana while we're at it, `str` is not a function, it's a type ;-)

Comment: Python has string formatting operations too, which are prefered over string concatenation.

Comment: That's one of the good things about Python (and other languages) that creating an instance of a type looks just like calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

This seems the problem:

```
print h+":"+m+":"+s
```

Cant concat string with int unless wrapping ints with str() or one of the options in this post

Check https://www.journaldev.com/23642/python-concatenate-string-and-int

Comment: Python has string formatting operations too, which are prefered over string concatenation.

Comment: Its in that link I posted too ... but you have to remove ad blocker haha

Answer (score 1):

The error line is here:

> > print h+":"+m+":"+s, use str() to convert it

Comment: Python has string formatting operations too, which are prefered over string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to keep track on the code without the full traceback and the actual line numbers, we just can't know for sure what you planned to do.

Anyway:

It's seems to be that the problem is in this line:

`print h+":"+m+":"+s`

Quick fix is to change this line of code to:

`print str(h)+":"+str(m)+":"+str(s)'

In that way, you convert the variable from `int` back to `string`.

And if you are using Python 3:

`print(str(h)+":"+str(m)+":"+str(s))`

By the way, Python provides us a better way of doing this staff without using converts/casts.

You should use format probably most of the times:

`print("{hour}:{minutes}:{seconds}".format(hour=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)`

You can read more about string formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python).

Thank you @[bruno desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) for clarifying it.

Comment: Python has string formatting operations too, which are prefered over string concatenation.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.
But I didn't want to complicate it  because as he said before, he has just started programming.

Comment: better to learn doing things the right way right from the start. Explaining why the op gets this error and how to convert ints to strings is fine, but _also_ mentionning string formatting is better.

Comment: You are probably right.
I have edited my answer, thank you :)

Comment: Well, thank to _you_ actually ;-) (nb SO is supposed to be a knowledge base, not a forum - IOW, when you answer a question, you want to try and make your answer useful not only for the OP but also to anyone else reading it).

Answer (score 0):

Basically to got a data type error. To concat a string you need to make all the datatypes match. The variables h, m and s are currently integers so you can use the str() function to convert them to. string.

Comment: Actually `str` is a type, not a function.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes string is a datatype but what I was talking about is the str() function that converts other datatypes into a string.

Comment: We're talking about the same thing - `str()` IS a type, not a class. Just open your python shell and type `type(str)`, you'll find out that it's a class (instance of type `type` - yes, `type` is a type too), not a function (which would be an instance of type `function`).

Comment: Fair enough I was just stating what I read in the python docs which calls it a function but your explanation also check out and make sense @brunodesthuilliers