# what does % mean in python when writing a string

Tags: python

So I was looking at a python tutorial, and in a statement, it used %.

```
print ("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)
```

Can someone please take their time and describe to me what that means. I'm pretty sure that it doesn't signify a division.

Comment: It's a C-style string formatting but it's is no longer used in python, So it's a quite old formatting technique.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

> Python uses C-style string formatting to create new, formatted
>   strings. The "%" operator is used to format a set of variables
>   enclosed in a "tuple" (a fixed size list), together with a format
>   string, which contains normal text together with "argument
>   specifiers", special symbols like "%s" and "%d".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the % sign in this case is supposed to be used for string formatting. This is an old technique and can be used with and f-string now. % is mostly used in java and not python.

Answer (score 0):

Python Program for 
Old Style Formatting 
of Integers also used %

```
Integer1 = 12.3456789
print("Formatting in 3.2f format: ") 
print('The value of Integer1 is %3.2f' %Integer1) 
print("\nFormatting in 3.4f format: ") 
print('The value of Integer1 is %3.4f' %Integer1)
```

Output:

```
Formatting in 3.2f format: 
The value of Integer1 is 12.35

Formatting in 3.4f format: 
The value of Integer1 is 12.3457
```

also use as

```
print("writing integer in a string: %s" %Integer1)
```

output

```
writing integer in a string: 12.3456789
```

Answer (score 0):

`% Employee.empCount` is a variable and `%d` for print integer variable.That's mean value of variable `% Employee.empCount` print in place of `%d`.

% sign use for give reference of variable.