# Matching Items in one Python list by session

Tags: python, list, loops, statistics, average

I have a **CSV** file of statistics that I am running a loop through to get the name, session, amount of time for reps, and count of reps of a person doing push-ups and situps. Each time the loop is run through the **list** is updated with the **next line of statistics**. Is there a way to find the **average time per session.**

```
**For example output:**
bob session1 average 20 seconds average 10 pushups 
bob session2 average 40 seconds average 18 situps 

**Lists being looped through:**
    lst = ['Bob',session 1, '10seconds', '5 pushups']
    lst = ['Bob',session 1, '30seconds', '15 pushups']
    lst = ['Bob',session 2, '25seconds', '10 situps']
    lst = ['Bob',session 2, '55seconds', '25 situps']
```

I was thinking of making a key = lst[1] that will record the session and work from there but 
I can't make sense of how I would do that. **Any ideas help, sorry for such a trivial question I am very new.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a list of tuples

```
lst=[('Bob','session 1', '10seconds', '5 pushups'),
    ('Bob','session 1', '30seconds', '15 pushups'),
    ('Bob','session 2', '25seconds', '10 situps'),
    ('Bob','session 2', '55seconds', '25 situps'),]
for item in lst:
    print('{} {} average {}  average {} '.format(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3]) )
```