# Add Column in a table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Am trying to add a column in the table salesperson. And it is showing error. Pls help. I am using the latest version of pycharm

[image: ERROR]

```
mycon = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='paswd', database='11b')
if mycon.is_connected():
    print('Connection established sucessfully.')
else:
    print('Connection not established.')
mycursor = mycon.cursor()

command = "alter table salesperson add {name} {data}"
name= input("Enter the name of column you want to :")
data= input("Enter the data type of the column:")
mycursor.execute(command)

query = "Select*from salesperson"
mycursor.execute(query)
result = mycursor.fetchall()
mycon.commit()
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using the name and data variables in the command variable but you declare them in the wrong order. Also, your command variable should be a f-string. I'd suggest you try something like this:

```
mycon = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='paswd', database='11b')
if mycon.is_connected():
    print('Connection established sucessfully.')
else:
    print('Connection not established.')
mycursor = mycon.cursor()

name= input("Enter the name of column you want to :")
data= input("Enter the data type of the column:")
command = f"alter table salesperson add {name} {data}"
mycursor.execute(command)

query = "Select*from salesperson"
mycursor.execute(query)
result = mycursor.fetchall()
mycon.commit()
for i in result:
    print(i)
```