# Dynamic Level in Pandas `date_range`

Tags: pandas, date-range

I wanted to make pandas `date_range` dynamic.

So, let x = 30 -- This can take any values.

```
pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-31', freq='xH')
```

`'30H'` is giving result, but not `'x30'`.

Can someone please guide me how to make it dynamic?

Comment: You can use [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic string formatting, here are two examples:

```
x = 30
pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-31', freq='%dH' % x)
```

```
x = 30
pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-31', freq=f'{x}H')
```