# How to put string inside string (variable) in Python?

Tags: python

I tried to run some python code, but it says "[pyflakes] unexpected EOF while parsing"

My code is:

```
if "debug " in code:
  print(" |" + x + "|" + y + "| ")
```

Edit: Also do NOT say duplicate I tried the answer of the other question and it didn't work. I use Python 3.8.2

Comment: which other question? also what is `code` and `x` and `y`? if I just assign empty strings (and `'debug'`) to those variables, it works fine for me

Comment: It looks like you are asking about string formatting. Is that not the case? Why is this *not* a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python

Comment: Please post more code than this, you're probably just missing a bracket or indent somewhere.

Comment: The error seems to be NOT RELATED at all with that code and purpose of string formatting. Please share hpw you run the program and the full stacktrace

Comment: There is no error in your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517355/string-formatting-in-python)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately, the code you have posted appears to be fine and it looks likely that the error you see is due to something else. Is there more to go on? Perhaps a line number where the error is encountered or is there more to the program that we might be able to see?

Answer (score 2):

Try using an f-string.

```
if "debug " in code:
  print(f" | {x} | {y} | ")
```

Comment: The error isn't related to the code, don't answer to such ;)